# XCode 7 source control account can't be deleted

Tags: xcode, git, svn, xcode7

My team just upgraded our project to XCode 7 on Friday and this morning we ran into a problem with source control.  Whenever someone tries to view the Blame or Log tabs, we are prompted to enter credentials to an SVN repo that we are no longer using.  In fact, someone on our team only implemented the SVN repo very briefly at the outset of the project over 18 months ago, and until now we didn't know it was still linked.

We see a repo labeled "trunk" under the Source Control menu in Xcode.  In **Preferences** --> **Accounts** tab we see the existing Git repo and the older SVN repo.  Deleting the SVN repo doesn't change the behavior; XCode still demands credentials.  Also, if we restart Xcode the deleted SVN repo returns.

We understand that there's probably something in the keychain or in the local folder that is prompting XCode to retain the account information but we're not seeing it.  Can anyone tell us how to permanently delete this SVN repo from XCode's Accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution.

Inside of the local git repo folder there was still a *hidden folder* named `.svn` that has been hanging around for the life of our project, apparently.  Although XCode 6 ignored this folder, XCode 7 recognized it as a valid definition for a source control repository and added the account at startup.

The solution:

1. Delete the hidden `.svn` folder
2. Delete the accounts associated with the invalid SVN repo under the **Preferences** --> **Accounts** tab
3. Restart XCode

I hope this can help someone else.